# Spring Integration - List file names being downloaded via a RemoteFileTemplate

Tags: spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I am downloading files via Sftp using a Spring Integration RemoteFileTemplate. How do I perform some processing on each file name that is being downloaded? I see that the line

.log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, "sftp.inbound", Message::getHeaders)

logs the file names but I need the file names available directly.

All I need to do is write the downloaded file names as a list into a POJO for passing as a response to a later process. My code is attached below.

`
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class SftpInboundFlowIntegrationConfig {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SftpInboundFlowIntegrationConfig.class);
private String sftpRemoteDirectory = "/";

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> inboundSftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    factory.setPort(2222);
    factory.setUser("local");
    factory.setPassword("local");
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sftpInboundFlow(RemoteFileTemplate<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> 
inboundRemoteFileTemplate) {
    return e -> e
            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, "sftp.inbound", Message::getPayload)
            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, "sftp.inbound", Message::getHeaders)
            .handle(
                    Sftp.outboundGateway(inboundRemoteFileTemplate, AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.MGET, "payload")
                            .localDirectory(new File("c:/tmp"))
            );
}

@Bean
public RemoteFileTemplate<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> inboundRemoteFileTemplate(SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> inboundSftpSessionFactory) {
    RemoteFileTemplate<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> template = new SftpRemoteFileTemplate(inboundSftpSessionFactory);
    template.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(sftpRemoteDirectory));
    template.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
    template.afterPropertiesSet();
    template.setUseTemporaryFileName(false);
    return template;
}
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all. I was trying to accomplish this in the wrong area of code. I realized that when I call my outbound gateway to download the files, sftpOutboundGateway.mget("/"); that it returns the list of files downloaded, which is what I needed.